# Unity dependency Injection framework doesn't work in my application

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, unity-container

I recently add unity dependency injection into my project before it. I havn't knowledge about it at all. I read article about it from  this link  [enter link description here](https://habr.com/post/176007/)

After this I tried to apply into my project but It don't run here is codes which I create

**1.Created interface**
here is I create interface and declare method of interface in our case it's only one method

```
 public  interface service1
    {

            bool check(string username, string login);
    }
```

**2. create it's implementation**

here is give implementation of interface in our case it looks like this

```
class Impl : service1
    {

        public bool check(string username, string password)
        {
            var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("IN CLASS");

            try
            {

                var bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(password);
                var hashBytes = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
                string hashedpassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

                PostgresqlDBQueryBuilder db = new PostgresqlDBQueryBuilder();
                db.pg_table("users");
                db.pg_where("username", username);
                db.pg_where("password", hashedpassword);
                DataTable res = db.pg_get();
                logger.Info("shordamiz");
                foreach (DataRow row in res.Rows)
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt16(row["id"]);
                    string db_username = row["username"].ToString();
                    string db_password = row["password"].ToString();
                    if (db_username == username && db_password == hashedpassword)
                    {
                        Session.UserID = id;
                        PostgresqlDBQueryBuilder db1 = new PostgresqlDBQueryBuilder();
                        db1.pg_table("warehouse_conf");
                        DataTable dt = db1.pg_get();
                        foreach (DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            Session.cur_code = row1["cur_code"].ToString();
                        }
                        //setCurrencies();
                        //MessageBox.Show(Session.cur_code);
                        /*Mainwindow main = new Mainwindow();
                        this.Hide();
                        main.ShowDialog();
                        this.Close();*/
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
//                errortext.Visible = true;
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //errortext.Visible = true;
                //   MessageBox.Show("Xatolik!!!"+ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }
```

**the main idea of this method just check from database is this login and password exist in database or not  boolean type of method**

**3.Create it's class to bind into unity container**

```
 public  class Register
    {

        readonly service1 ss;
        public Register(service1 ss) 
        {
            this.ss = ss;
        }
        public bool check(string login, string password)
        {
            var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            logger.Info("IN CLASS");
            return ss.check( login , password);

        }
    }
```

from articl there were given example like this that's why this class was created to resolve and to use 
**The main part using this all method is class following**
**After clicking some button from our view this method will run following code**

```
    try
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        var varior = container.Resolve<Register>();
        logger.Info("kemiydi");                        

        if (varior.check(username_input.Text, password_input.Text))
        {
            Mainwindow main = new Mainwindow();
            this.Hide();
            main.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            errortext.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
}
```

but anyway Unity dependency injection don't work somehow? what's wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Do you get a compiler error? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I get exception

Comment: It looks like you did not register your service, i.e. `container.RegisterType<service1, Impl>();`